# Flutter Testing LateInitializationError in my class?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I have a class that helps me handle the sharedpreferences:

```
class SharedPref {
  static late final SharedPreferences prefs;

  static initialize() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  SharedPref._();

  static Future<void> save(String key, String value) async {
    await prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  // more methods that help me to save/load values...
}
```

Then I have a testing function:

```
class MockNavigatorObserver  extends Mock implements NavigatorObserver {}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Button is present and triggers navigation after tapped',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {

        final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          MaterialApp(
            home: FirstPage(),
            navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
          ),
        );

        expect(find.byType(RaisedButton), findsOneWidget);
        await tester.tap(find.byType(RaisedButton));
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        expect(find.byType(MyDetailedPage), findsOneWidget);
      });
}
```

Whenever I run the test:

```
The following LateError was thrown running a test:
LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.
```

How am I supposed to initialize that? I called the `SharedPref.initialize();` before the `final mockObserver...` but made no change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's recommended to use singleton over static in you class. To be one instance over runtime application.

Comment: How this comment helps on my problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned problem was in

```
final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
```

not inside main() function.

But it was another silly mistake with this kind error if wright initialisation like this:

```
late final MockNavigatorObserver mockObserver;

setUp(() {
    mockObserver= MockNavigatorObserver();
})
```

Problem in this case is using **final** keyword. If use like that, only one test will pass. You need not using final keyword, instead:

```
late MockNavigatorObserver mockObserver;
    
    setUp(() {
        mockObserver= MockNavigatorObserver();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

> I called the SharedPref.initialize(); before

You need to `await` the call, otherwise you have race conditions when your `save` is called and `initalize` may or may not already be finished.

Comment: If I do that, running of the test never stops.

Comment: Nevermind. I called it in the main() function and not in the test so it works fine.